# How to show marker location from localStorage in react leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to show the saved marker location once the page is refreshed but so far no luck. The `App` is deployed here: https://master.d8pjybx1mf2s7.amplifyapp.com

It's a basic `app` to find if User 2 is in range of User 1. We can mark locations by clicking on the map.

```
 handleClick(e){
    this.setState({ currentPos: e.latlng });
    localStorage.setItem('Poslat1', this.state.currentPos.lat);
    localStorage.setItem('Poslon1', this.state.currentPos.lng);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      
      <div>
        <Map center={this.props.center} zoom={this.props.zoom} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <TileLayer
              url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          />
          
          { this.state.currentPos && <MyMarker icon={LocationIcon}  position={this.state.currentPos}>

          </MyMarker>}
        {this.state.currentPos && <Circle center={this.state.currentPos} pathOptions={{fillColor: 'blue' }} radius={1000} />}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I am able to store the location data by using `localStorage` which is used to find range, I thought I could same method to somehow save the marker location on map as well but it's not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the component mounts check if `lat1` and `lon1` exist in your `localStorage` and if they do change the component state

```
componentDidMount() {
   const lat1 = localStorage.getItem("Poslat1");
   const lon1 = localStorage.getItem("Poslon1");
   if (lat1 && lon1) this.setState({ currentPos: [lat1, lon1] });
}
```

then upon refresh they will be persisted.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-show-marker-location-from-localstorage-in-react-leaflet-v2x-g8dpy)